# Toggle jQuery .animate function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a situation where on click, menu items slide out then spread out vertically. I've kind of achieved this but when the menu is closed and reopened, the menu items pickup where they left off and spread out even further!

How do I toggle or reset the vertical movement?

My jQuery:

```
    $('.box').click(function(){
    $('.tab1').toggle("slide", { direction: "left"}, 500);
    $('.tab2').toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
    $('.tab3').toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
});
 $('.box').click(function(){
       $('.tab1').animate({top:'+=50px'}); 
       $('.tab3').animate({top:'-=50px'});    
});
```

html:

```
<div class="square">
    <div class="box">
        CLICK
        <div class="tab1 tab"></div>
        <div class="tab2 tab"></div>
        <div class="tab3 tab"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.square{
    margin-left:100px;
}
.box{
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;

 }

.tab{
    width:70px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:grey;
    display:none;
}
.tab1{
   position:absolute;
    right:-70px;
    top:50px;
}
.tab2{
   position:absolute;
    right:-70px;
    top:50px;
}

.tab3{
   position:absolute;
    right:-70px;
    top:50px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidhudson/uWYzg/53/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create toggle functionality for the other animations as well

```
$('.box').click(function(){
    var flag = $(this).data('flag');

    $('.tab1').toggle("slide", { direction: "left"}, 500);
    $('.tab2').toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
    $('.tab3').toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);

    $('.tab1').animate({top: (flag ? '+=50px' : '-=50px')}); 
    $('.tab3').animate({top: (flag ? '-=50px' : '+=50px')});    

    $(this).data('flag', !flag)
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/uWYzg/55/)